# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' in google coral mendel 4.0

Tags: opencv, google-coral

https://coral.withgoogle.com/news/updates-11-2019/

As per above google coral November updates new Mendel 4.0 has the support of OpenCV but when I installed Mendel 4.0 it is unable to import cv2. Please let me know do I've to follow any further steps to install OpenCV in Mendel 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following steps have to be done:

1. If you have a fresh image make sure you update your system packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
2. Install OpenCV

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-opencv
   ```
3. Test installation

   ```
   python3 -c 'import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)'
   ```

I can confirm, that openCV can be installed using `sudo apt install python3-opencv`. If it does not work, check if your board is connected to the internet (see coral documentation [here](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started#3-connect-to-the-internet)).

Comment: Thank you it worked!! but don't know why for every frame Corrupt JPEG data: 4 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd5 message is coming in prompt.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it with

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
```

Comment: it is not working!! mendel@purple-dog:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-opencv 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-opencv

Comment: Please see the answer above, you need to do a full distribution upgrade.